# Is Build a class or Build.VERSION is a single class ?

Tags: android

In Android, when we write,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
```

In this, Build is a class and `VERSION` is a constant in it then what is `SDK_INT` 
 or if,
 `Build.VERSION` itself is a single class and SDK_INT is constant in it ?

Comment: refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Comment: You can verify this by yourself by checking Android source code.

Answer (score 1):

`android.os.Build` is a class.

`android.os.Build` has two public static inner classes, `VERSION` and `VERSION_CODES`.

Values like `SDK_INT` in `VERSION` and `HONEYCOMB` in `VERSION_CODES` are `public static final int` data members.

You can see this in [the source code to `android.os.Build`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java).

Comment: thanks for the answer,So that means that in android the inner classes do not follows the pascal notation..

Comment: @AmitBhandari: Since I have no idea what "the pascal notation" is, I cannot answer that.

Comment: Like in java we follow pascal notation where the first letter of each word in the name of a class is capital as- NullPointerException.   and for the constants all letters are in capital as -  YES_OPTION.. so looking at VERSION it looks more as a constant that the name of a class..

Comment: Yes, the convention in Java is to follow CamelCase (what you call PascalNotation) for class names. The same is true for Android inner classes (e.g. View.OnClickListener). However, there is also the convention to use UPPER_CASE for constant values. Since everything in android.os.Build is a constant, it is in upper case.